# apache velocity - limits on tables/lists?

Tags: templates, velocity

I have noticed that velocity doesn't allow me to create lists or tables with more elements than ca. 53. is it a known problem?

I get the following error:
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 101; columnNumber: 22; The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
    ... 16 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity doesn't have such a limit on tables or lists. Plus, Velocity doesn't parse the generated result as XML: it's probably the framework you're using that is issuing this exception (the whole stack trace would be interesting).

The most probable cause is that there is an error in your template, for instance an HTML attribute value which is missing its ending quote.

If you have access to the generated HTML before the exception is thrown, you can try opening it in a browser and inspect its structure to see where the problem lies.

Comment: you are right, the problem was invalid data in 54th element (some characters needed to be escaped)